# Learning C++ and I don't know what I did wrong here

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning C++ and I was asked to write a code using the while function. The code runs, but it gives does not print the line `Dear ...`. What did I do wrong here?

```
    cout << "Hello! Please write your recipient and the letter, then press enter:\n";
string name{ "" };
string current{ "" };
string letter{ "" };
cin >> name;
while (cin >> current){
    if (current != name){
        letter += " " + current;
    }
}
cout << "Dear " << name << "," << letter;
keep_window_open();
return 0;
```

Comment: `while (cin >> current)` When do you expect your `while` loop condition to evaluate to `false`?

Comment: It doesn't even output `Hello! Please write your recipient and the letter, then press enter:` ?

Comment: @clcto it does output the first line, it just doesn't output the result

Comment: To see output use `std::endl` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: @user2023328 _'it just doesn't output the result'_ You're stuck in the loop, so what do you expect?

Comment: @Cyber I used the while condition from an example in my book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To output the result you have to make `cin >> current` false. To do this, use `Ctrl-D` to send end of file (EOF) to `cin` which will cause the loop to stop executing.

Edit: Apparently in Windows, the sequence is `Ctrl-Z`.

Edit: As @pdw noted, `cout` will need to be flushed. This is usually done when there is a newline character, but since you don't have one you can use `std::flush` or `std::endl`:

```
cout << "Dear " << name << "." << letter << std::flush;
```

Comment: And cout is line-buffered, so a newline needs to be added the "Dear ..." line before it's output.

Comment: @pdw, I am pretty sure `cout` clears it buffer before the program exits.

Comment: He has a `keep_window_open()` call at the end of his code, so his program will probably not exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cin >> current)
```

To make this loop interrupt you need to put end of stream marker into `std::cin`. Type `Ctrl-Z` on Windows or `Ctrl-D` on Unix like systems at the end of input to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop here.  `while (cin >> current)` will always evaluate to true, and will just continuously wait for user input. That is why you never reach the last line of code.  You are just continuously creating new values for current on each input in the prompt and then adding them to letter.  I would recommend not using a while loop, or set some escape input.  For example, if the user enters done, exit from the loop, using `break;`